# Server response handlers for google.script.run

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

How do I specify BOTH a success AND a failure handler for the same server call with google.script.run?

Answer (score 11):

The following code should do what you need

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(myFailureHandler).withSuccessHandler(handler1);
```

It is [documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#script_runners) in the `Success and Failure Handlers` paragraph. The text starts with

> You can use any combination of withSuccessHandler, withFailureHandler,
>   and withUserObject.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not used to chaining in JavaScript.